# Java/ read from .txt file

Tags: java

I have .txt file, and I want to read from it to char array.

I have problem, in the .txt file I have:

```
1  a

3  b

2  c
```

which mean that a[1]='a', a[3]='b', a[2]='c'.

How in reading the file, I ignore from spaces, and consider the new lines? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean `char[] a` or `String[] a`?

Comment: Could the values be also alphabetic chars, or only integers?

Comment: Please provide your current code and where exactly you have a problem

Comment: @JScoobyCed: I don't know which instruction I need to use to

Comment: Can you post the source code that reads the file so someone can guide you where and what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a `Map` for this instead since it's better suited for this kind of problems.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner("1 a 3 b 2 c"); // or new File(...)

    TreeMap<Integer, Character> map = new TreeMap<Integer, Character>();

    while (s.hasNextInt())
        map.put(s.nextInt(), s.next().charAt(0));
}
```

---

If you would like to convert the `TreeMap` to `char[]` you can do the following:

```
char[] a = new char[map.lastKey() + 1];

for (Entry<Integer, Character> entry : map.entrySet())
    a[entry.getKey()] = entry.getValue();
```

Notes:

- This solution does not work with negative indexes
- Takes only the "first" character if more than one

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

```
ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner s = new Scanner(yourFile);
while(s.hasNextInt()) {
    int i = s.nextInt();
    String n = s.next();
    a.add(n);
}
```

Of course, this boldly assumes correct input; you should be more paranoid. If you need to deal with each line specially, you can use `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`, and then split the line using `split()` from the String class.